# Можно ли в Python не просто отправить email, а отправить ответ на письмо?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

Есть ли техническая возможность отправить ответ на письмо с помощью `Python`?

У меня не возникает проблем просто с отправкой почты, но сейчас возникла потребность именно отвечать на почту, чтобы получатель видел переписку "до".

Добавление в письмо заголовков `In-Reply-To` и `References` не помогает.

Comment: Ответ ничем не отличается от обычного письма. Если нужна переписка «до», вы  должны самостоятельно добавить её в текст письма

Comment: Добавь Re: в тему